# Make a simple wp page into woocommerce page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a sidebar that shows on the Woocommerce page but not on the other Wordpress simple pages due to this line in widgets

```
    if( !class_exists('WooCommerce') ){
        return;
    }
    if( !is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && !is_tax( get_object_taxonomies( 'product' ) ) ){
        return;
    }
```

I want a simple wp page to react as a woo commerce page so that this sidebar can be shown on it.

Comment: _"I want a simple wp page to react as a woo commerce page"_ - that makes rather little sense. Your page would still need to "identify" as either the product archive page, or the current "post" (the page) would have to have the taxonomy `product`- both doesn't make too much sense, and could lead to trouble elsewhere. _"due to this line in widgets"_ - what kind of widget is that? What happens _next_ in there?

Comment: Your question makes little sense, but I think what you're getting at is that you want to create a custom template for a particular WooCommerce view. It's easily achievable if you understand the concept and practice of theme templates, template hierarchy, and template override functionality in the WordPress application. However, it can't be answered in just one simple answer. Study those topics and then you'll get it.